# I am trying to make an login page and sign up page with firebase . I want to use firebase realtime database for store username and email

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword this method is working but the database method not working.
i make the values true in realtime database .

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            user u = new user(username,email);
                            >the below method is not working
                            database.child(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                                    .setValue(u).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(signUp.this,"done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(signUp.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(signUp.this,"loginfailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Comment: "the database method not working" doesn't help. If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. The problem is only occurring in the emulator . In the physical device, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

**1) Did you initialize your `database reference`:**

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**2) Did you initialize your `auth`:**

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

**3) Are your `security rules` for real time database allowing read and write?**

**4) Are your `email` and `password` that are being passed to the function null?**

Comment: yes i auth,, I noticed this same code is running perfectly on physical device, but this problem occurs in emulator